# User Dashboard - Confused

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, dashboard

I'm currently creating a website where each registered user has a dashbaord. The dashbaord has columns which show the location of their listing of which they can have many.

I'm unsure how to model this. Currently when a user creates a item the status column in the listing is set to 1. This is value for live. I can set the status value to 2,3,4 for the other respective values - however this causes a problem. If the value is two, the listing will appear in the purchased box, but it would also appear in the purchase box on the sellers dashboard.

[ScreenShot of Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umBE2.png)

How should I model this/ build it to ensure two users can interact with it in different ways.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to implement the desired model.
You could simply add two different status for each item, let's say `seller_status`, `user_status`. If the item only belongs to just one seller and one user, this approach is fine.

Alternatively, if you have multiple users who can own the same item. You should create a unique reference table, let's say, `UsersItems` with `belongs_to: users` and `belongs_to: seller`. This way the actual item listing for the seller uses the status of `Item` model and each user listing status uses it's own status from `UsersItems`.

The latter approach is preferable if you plan on expanding further the interactions between each User and the Items, cause you can store specific information about their relation on their unique `UsersItems` entry.

However, it's difficult to say if this is exactly what you need. Cause you didn't say what are those items and how they relate to both `User` and `Seller` I don't even know if they are the same table. If you want to elaborate on your question by explaining what you hope to achieve and the Database Table I can further expand on the topic.

Comment: Thanks for this! I'm only learning and it can be difficult to get my head around everything. Basically - Users can upload items which other users can then purchase. I want these items to be displayed in the respective users dashboards i.e. Purchased (for the buyer) and Sold (for the seller). At the moment there is two models. A devise user model and a listing model. Each user has many listings & each listing has one user? How would you model the second (purchase user) into the model?

Comment: If every user can purchase and sell, then I'd keep the `user` model as it is and implement the second option I mentioned. Which means, whenever a `user` creates a `listing` (horrible name btw) it means he's selling it. So the `user_id` represents the seller. When a user wants to purchase an `Item` (let's use that instead) it can will create an entry on a reference model `UserItems`. Which references both `user` (buyer) and `item`. This way the number of `UserItems` belonging to a user is the number of items bought. The number of `Items` belonging to a user is the number of items sold.

Comment: Other people might have different opinions on the matter. You should edit your post and clarify what you just explained me.  Maybe describe your models and include some codes as well. If you do so, I'll update my answer and format the answer in the appropriated way. You can follow the question guidelines to know how to properly ask a question - [Guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)